# Replace color code with glyphicon

Tags: php, html, css

I have table which consist of color code. See the image attached. I wanted to replace the color code with Glyphicon instead, for example like...

```
<i class="fa fa-smile-o"></i>
```

into these codes below

```
while ($data = $search_result->fetch_assoc()) {
if(round($data['Duration1']) <= 3 && round($data['Duration1']) >= 0)
{
$done_color = "#00FF00";

}
else if(round($data['Duration1']) <= 5 && round($data['Duration1']) >= 4)
{
$done_color = "#FFFF00";
}
else
{
$done_color = "#FF0000";
}
```

So is it possible for it to be like..

```
 $done_color = "fa fa-smile-o";
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noNiX.png)

p/s: please ignore the value in the table.

Comment: Please read the following carefully: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: How are color codes related to glyphicons? You can't just "replace" color codes with icons, there's more to it. Post your code, please

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Comment: post more your exact html

Comment: we dont know how you are displaying $done_color, without that we cant help here

Comment: I updated my post

Comment: It seems like you want font-awesome to change the icon based on some logic? If you are dealing with only 2-5 symbols you want to use, i suggest you to use some JavaScript and set up the statements for each case. Please clarify if that is what you are looking for, i post then an example. Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what you exactly want, but maybe this helps:

```
<i class="<?php echo $done_color; ?>"></i>
```

Echo the variable with the icon class to show the right icon.